# Installing pvc molding

Tags: trim

Installing pvc molding, so we don't have to prime and paint. What s the best method to fill nail holes. As i stated we are not painting. Also have 1 wall where i have to butt 2 pieces of molding together, and the best method for that is?
  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is a dab of painter's caulk right from the tube. As it dries, it may dip a bit, but you can hit it again the next day. The white version should pretty much disappear against the white of pvc.

I might glue the butt joint to keep it tight, but once again, a smear of caulk can mask a bit of a gap.